# Combine Sass and plain CSS into one file with Laravel Elixir

Tags: php, css, gulp, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

How do you combine plain CSS and Sass file with Laravel Elixir? If I run the following code then two files "all.css" and "app.css" is generated on the `public/CSS/` directory. However, I only want to generate one CSS file which would be `all.css`. Do you guys know any tricks to do it?

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass([
            'app.scss'
        ])
        .styles([
            'owl.carousel.css'
        ]);
})
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I usualy do it this way. Directory structure:

```
/public
    /css 
        all.css
/resources
    /css
        app.css
    /sass
        app.scss
```

The code should look like this:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass([
        'app.sass'
    ], 'resources/assets/css/custom.css')
    .styles([
        '/resources/assets/css/app.css',
        '/resources/assets/css/custom.css',
    ], 'public/css/all.css', __dirname);
})
```

This will first create custom.css file in */resources/assets/css/custom.css* and then all css files in this folder will be merged in one file located in */public/css*.

Comment: There is a problem with this in debug mode. Because elixir will create sourcemaps, it causes 404 network error for `custom.css.map` because it doesn't exists in public path. Disabling sourcemaps also prevents you to debug in local environment. I searched for a way to disable sourcemap just for Sass, but had no luck.

Comment: Hi, how to do this if one of your css is inside the node_modules folder? What is the path to be given?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be as clean as separating directories, but a SASS file compiles to a CSS file, so in theory you can pass a normal css file into the elixir mixer:

```
mix.sass(['app.scss', 'jumbotron-narrow.scss', 'datepicker_standalone3.css']);
```

The end-result is a single app.css file in the corresponding public directory.

Comment: This will throw errors complaining about missing the sass `src` parameter if you try it. Does not work.

Comment: Works for me `mix.sass(['app.scss', 'libs/*.css']);` is OK too!